# Retrofit multipart request

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I am using retrofit2+rxAndroid to work with REST. I want to send multipart request with image and text. But something is not working and instead of image+ text I have this "trim,nshtml,max|140".

This is my request:

```
 @Multipart
    @POST("feed/post/add")
    public Observable<VehicleSearchResponse>
    addPost(@Header("Authorization") String token, @Header("Content-Type") String contenttype,
            @Part("text") String message,
            @Part("attached_images") RequestBody file);
```

And this is how I form my RequestBody

```
 RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpg"), persistImage(bitmap2, "test"))
```

Please help me.

Comment: I changed my request to @Multipart
        @POST("feed/post/add")
        public Observable<VehicleSearchResponse>
        addPost(@Header("Authorization") String token,
                @Part("attached_images\"; filename=\"image.jpg\" ") RequestBody file,@Part("text") String test
        ); But now my text part looks like "text"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using:

```
MultipartBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, bytes)
```

for the attached_images part?